# HTML Animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, animation

I came across a site where they have done nice animation. I am not able to make out if they have used any tools for this or most of this is custom coding. from HTML source it seems they are using Angular JS etc..

http://viewfromabove.emirates.com/3d

I had few question regarding this site

1. Is it custom animation or they have used some third part tool to generate this animation
2. How are they animation Globe is it a 3d image or pure HTML based animation of globe.

Comment: You mean they have used 3rd party tool or it is custom animation

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: you can save it as image..

Comment: I'm messing with you - this question is doomed

Comment: For 2 it's a rendered image on a HTML `<canvas>`. So it's not the "HTML" approach in the sense that the globe is not composed of HTML elements.

Answer (score 4):

It's using [THREE.js](http://threejs.org/).

It's a rendered 3D object.

Answer (score 1):

It's [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) rendering done with the [THREE.js](http://threejs.org/) library, and audio via [howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library).

As Nick says, it's not just an animation, it's a 3D scene being rendered in the browser. It's 2016, most browsers can do that now.